# Validating a dropbox to ensure users have selected a value

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am trying to validate my dropbox to ensure that the user has selected a quiz. But when I select a different quiz in the dropbox, the result is equal to "1" and it alerts this to me, but it not running correctly, it runs the code for when the result is equal to "0".

```
<select id="quiz" onchange="check()">
  <option value="0">Select Quiz</option>
    <?php foreach ($datas as $data) : ?>
      <option value="1"><?php echo $data['Title']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<script>
  var x = false;
  function check() {
    var e = document.getElementById("quiz");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(result);
    if(result = "0") {
      alert("Select a quiz");
    }else if (result = "1") {
      alert("UTM");
      x = true;
    }
  }
  function Validate() {
    if(x == true) {
      alert("UTM");
    } else {
      alert ("Please select a quiz");
    }
  }
</script>
</b>
</label>
<button type="enter" onclick="Validate()">Confirm Selection</button>
```

Comment: it would be better to have running HTML sample, please add the generated HTML code  with javascript without PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Your validate function does not even read the state if X = true, even if it is already modified by onchange, so the output will alway be false.

I would recommend combining change and validate function to one as two functions for the same are not relevant in this case

Also 1 = 1 does not work, either use == or ===

```
<select id="quiz">
<option value="0">Select Quiz</option>
<option value="1">Quiz1</option>
<option value="1">Another quiz</option>
</select>
<button type="enter" onclick="Validate()">Confirm Selection</button>

<script>
  function Validate() {
    var e = document.getElementById("quiz");
    var result = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    alert(result);
    if(result == 0) {
      alert("Select a quiz");
    }else if (result == 1) {
      alert("UTM");
      x = true;
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there's a typo in your code with your `if` statement.

`if(result = "0") {`

Here, you're making an assignment so this condition will be alwais true.

what you should do instead:

`if(result == "0") {` or `if(parseInt(result) === 0) {`

same goes for the line underneath: `else if (result = "1") {`

have you ever heard about yoda conditions ? it helps avoiding those small mistakes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions